# How to turn off CalendarView in a DatePicker?

Tags: android, android-layout

On my settings screen I have a date picker widget. In the designer in Eclipse, it shows as I want (3 spinners for D-M-Y) but when I test on my device, I get a rather odd view with a side spinner on the left and a calendar on the right. Never seen this before(!) but doing some research I think I'm seeing the "CalendarView".

I found that I should be able to set a "calendarViewShown" property to false- but my XML throws an error with this. I found another question on here that suggested the API level was to blame (my minSDKLevel is 7, but I'm targetting 11 so I can get the action bar button rather than the oldskool menu).
So I thought I'd try setting it in code:

```
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= 11)
        minDateSelector.setCalendarViewShown = false;
```

But again, this fails- setCalendarViewShown isn't found. But the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) say it should exist.
Any ideas?!

Comment: add @SuppressLint("NewApi") in eclipse to suppress the warning and do what SoloCrowd suggested.

Comment: what is minDateSelector ?

Answer (score 98):

If you are targeting a later version of the API, you can use the following XML (no need to write Java code) in your `<DatePicker>`:

```
 android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#attr_android:calendarViewShown - according to this documentation, it is only applicable for the "spinner" mode.

Comment: Ok, so how do you do it if you *want* to write Java code?

Comment: @Michael you may use `setCalendarViewShown (boolean shown)` if you want to write Java code

Comment: double check this.  in the text view of the XML, it might be setting `tools:calanderViewShown`.  change this to `android:calendarViewShown`

Answer (score 32):

The method in DatePicker

```
    public void setCalendarViewShown (boolean shown)
```

exists starting with API 11. If you minSdkLevel = 7 the compiler does not recognize this as a valid method - the method does not exist on android 2.3 or 2.2. The best way is to solve this is using reflection. Something like this should work properly:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= 11) {
  try {
    Method m = minDateSelector.getClass().getMethod("setCalendarViewShown", boolean.class);
    m.invoke(minDateSelector, false);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {} // eat exception in our case
}
```

Comment: You should always target the latest SDK; this is avoid needing to use reflection.

Comment: perfectly fine for me. thanks! if the user is using < 11 he's not my target audience anyway. at least i save him/her from a crash now ;)

Answer (score 15):

I made it work with the following XML configuration:

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

Only the following configuration didn't work for me:

```
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

Answer (score 10):

In those cases I use

```
import android.os.Build;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void someThing() {
    [...]

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        minDateSelector.setCalendarViewShown(false);
    }
}
```

I think the readability is better than using reflection and the style is better than catch and ignore exceptions. Of course the reflection thing is also working.

Comment: what is minDateSelector ?

Comment: @Jilberta It's an instance of a [`DatePicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you, I couldn't make the change appear via XML.

You are on the right track, try changing your last line to:

```
minDateSelector.setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

Comment: Thanks - I've changed to a different UI option now, but I might re-visit the datepicker instead, sounds like the above will work!