# Android Datepicker displays calendar instead of year

Tags: android, android-layout

Running into an issue with Datepicker - not sure if I misunderstanding how it should be used.  In the graphic layout editor I added a Datepicker and I added that layout to my activity.  When I run the application the month and day show up fine but instead of a year I see a calendar and I'm not sure why.  Any ideas?

[click for screenshot of the issue](http://screencast.com/t/hgDU3jbmwhs)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>



public class BirthdayActivity extends Activity {    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_birthday);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default its shown. You can set it to false with this:

```
setCalendarViewShown(boolean shown)
```

First line of [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#getCalendarView%28%29) :

> This class is a widget for selecting a date. The date can be selected
>   by a year, month, and day spinners or a [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html).
>   And another related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462448/how-to-turn-off-calendarview-in-a-datepicker).

Comment: Thanks but it looks like I'm running into a NullPointerException after adding this to my activity:DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1); datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false); setContentView(R.layout.activity_birthday);

Comment: put setContentView(...) as your first line after super.onCreate(...)