# How to remove calender view from DatePickerDialog in android?

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I need to remove Calender view from DatePickerDialog.

Code:

```
// Process to get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Launch Date Picker Dialog
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    // Display Selected date in textbox
                    _tvDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                            + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.show();
```

Please help me out.
Thanks Kind regards.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462448/how-to-turn-off-calendarview-in-a-datepicker

Comment: @MaheeraJazi-newaccount- I have not used DatePicker in XML.
I am only having this.

Comment: try this in onDateSet()

    view.setCalendarViewShown(false);

Comment: I have used the same code before, it should not show calendar.

Answer (score 0):

try this code before dpd.show();

```
 dpd.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
```