# Why is my android DatePicker displaying a calendar?

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm new to programming Android apps and I'm following this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm

and I don't know why I'm getting a calendar DatePicker displayed instead of a spinner. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xxxx);
   datePicker=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.xxx);

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                    if (currentapiVersion >= 11)
                    {
                        datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);

                    }
      datePicker.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
}
```

> [How to turn off CalendarView in a DatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462448/how-to-turn-off-calendarview-in-a-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker theme is depends on Android OS Version.

If you don't want calendar view then you can hide it using below code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    mDatePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
}
```

If you are using in XML file then use below code.

```
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Date Picker object behavior depends on the android version. Use this

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= 11)
         minDateSelector.setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

Comment: Thanks Ketan, where would I add this?